# How to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, security, redirect, https, http-redirect

I want to redirect my all urls from http to https I am able to do so with given code.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/$1" [L,R=301]
```

But issue is that when my url is like `http://domain.com/admin/users/login` then it redirects to  `https://www.domain.com/users/login` how can I redirect this on `https://www.domain.com/admin/users/login`

Comment: Add the `/admin` in the destination URL before `/$1`?

Comment: /admin is just an example actually its dynamic variable changes every time. That's an issue.

Comment: You're not capturing `$1` by putting brackets. `RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.domain.com/$0 [L,R=301]` will work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```